# How to solve the equation $3x-4\lfloor x\rfloor=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

As a homework, I was asked to solve this **equation**, $$(3x-4\lfloor x\rfloor=0),x\in \Bbb R$$ For $x\in \Bbb Z:\lfloor x\rfloor=x \implies x=0$ But for $x\not\in\Bbb Z : \lfloor x\rfloor=\frac 34x$ So now we know that $\frac 34x\in\Bbb Z$ and $x\in\Bbb R-\Bbb Z$, so maybe ? define a function such that : $$f:\begin{Bmatrix}(\Bbb R-\Bbb Z)\to \Bbb Z \\ x\mapsto \frac34x\end{Bmatrix}$$ Even if trying this did walk me into $x=\frac43$ I'm still left with no *rigorous* proof (An explanation is would be nice if possible). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: All $4k | k\in \Bbb Z$

Comment: I don't know how to specify the right ones.

Comment: But $x=0$ isn't the only solution, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x=n+\epsilon$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq\epsilon<1$

Then the equation becomes $$3n+3\epsilon=4n\implies 3\epsilon=n$$

Therefore, $0\leq\frac n3<1\implies n=0,1,2$ and correspondingly, $\epsilon=0, \frac 13,\frac 23$

Therefore the solutions are $$x=0,\frac 43,\frac 83$$

Comment: Very cool, as an onlooker who has never seen this type of problem before I found your answer intuitive and satisfying, thank you!

Comment: @David Quinn: For completeness you should add the negative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

rewrite this as $4\lfloor x \rfloor =3x$, so that $x=\frac{n}{3}$ for some integer $n$.

We now have $4\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor=n$

Comment: now you only have to work with integers, can you finish from here?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You can rewrite $3x=4\lfloor x \rfloor$ as $3\left(\lfloor x \rfloor+\{x\}\right)=4\lfloor x \rfloor$, so $\lfloor x \rfloor=3\{x\}$.

Since $0\le \{x\}<1,\; 0\le \lfloor x \rfloor<3$  and therefore $\lfloor x \rfloor\in \{0, 1, 2\}$

Answer (score 0):

### $$3x=4\lfloor x\rfloor$$

Suppose that, for some integer, $n$, we know that $n \le x \lt n+1$. Then 
$\lfloor x\rfloor = n$ and 
$$x = \dfrac 43n$$

But we still need to make sure that

\begin{array}{cccC}
   n &\le &x &\lt &n+1 \\
   n &\le &\dfrac 43n &\lt &n+1 \\
   3n &\le &4n &\lt &3n+3 \\
   0 &\le &n &\lt &3 \\
\end{array}

So $n \in \{0,1,2\}$; that is, $x \in \left\{ 0,\dfrac 43,\dfrac 83 \right\}$