# Solve in $\mathbb{R}$ the equation $3-4\lfloor x\rfloor=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Solve in  $\mathbb{R}$ the following equation :
$$3-4\lfloor x\rfloor=0$$

indeed,
$$3-4\lfloor x\rfloor=0 \iff 3=4\lfloor x\rfloor \iff \lfloor x\rfloor=\dfrac{3}{4}$$ this is impossible since $\dfrac{3}{4}\notin \mathbb{Z}$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad \lfloor x\rfloor \in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Good, and the solution is $\varnothing$.

Comment: [Oddly similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2076656/120540) but with $3x$ instead of $3$.

Comment: why downvote am i wrong

Comment: @Yacob No, you are right.  I don't know why they downvoted you, but I can't counter-upvote because I ran out of upvotes today.  :(

Comment: Thank you for ur explanations :)

Comment: I think a downvote is too much, but an answer is also not necessary (and you have accepted none of the answers to your last ten questions).

Comment: Take into account the remark of @Dietrich Burde about your non acceptance of answers. I would say it is discourteous for people who have spend time to answer you not to validate (one of) their answer(s) 2 weeks later... I think a delay of 4-5 days is enough for having convenient answers on this site.

Comment: I think I'd have to agree.  There are more than plenty very good answers on many of your questions.  While not a reason for downvoting your questions, we'd recommend you go recheck your old questions